# App submission on app store gives warning "Missing 64-bit support"

Tags: ios, app-store

I am uploading an app to the App Store. But unfortunately I get the below warning.
[image: Archive submission failed due to Warning ITMS-9000: "Missing 64-bit support. Starting February 1, 2015, new iOS apps uploaded to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK, included in Xcode 6 or later."]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26796934/1702413

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS app submission : missing 64-bit support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790554/ios-app-submission-missing-64-bit-support)

Answer (score 6):

As the warning says, your app isn't prepared for 64-bit, and apple announced a month ago that starting in february 2015 all the apps uploaded to the app store must support it. So, it seems that if you're using iOS 8 you got to enable 64-bit support on you app now.

For supporting 64 bit you got to have in your project build settings the following:
[image]

Comment: I did it as your answer but is there any thing need to change in Architectures ?
That shows me "Standard architectures(armv7,arm64) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)".

Comment: I edited my answer with the full Architectures section, hope it helps

Comment: I am using standard architectures but still getting the warning.

Comment: I had a typo. In the "Valid Architectures" section I had "armv64" instead of "arm64". Make sure that both your "Valid Architectures" and "Architectures" sections match what is shown above.

Comment: I have edited all section as per above image but its not working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same issue. Property `Architecture` was set to `Standard architectures`, but it did not help.
What fixed the problem... I set `Build Active Architecture Only` to `No` even for `Debug`.
App was successfully submitted. Also after archiving the app I saw that estimated size was larger then last time (means it worked).

Hope it helped.

Answer (score 0):

After updating Architectures to Standard architectures(armv7,arm64) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD) it may still NOT work if you have used frameworks in your app.
I tried updating frameworks internal(UIKit,UIMapKit, etc) and external (facebook,crashlytics, etc) and worked for me. 
Means any framework that is not updated to 64-bit version will force the app to change to 32-bit and hence will not be submitted successfully on the app store.
Hope this helps!!