# sthttprequest and jsonkit with arm64, not work anymore?

Tags: ios, iphone, jsonkit, sthttprequest

I'm creating and update of one of my app, it uses sthttprequest and jsonkit. From this february apple require the supporting for 64 bit architectures, i have already seen this warning in the past months :

[iOS app submission : missing 64-bit support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790554/ios-app-submission-missing-64-bit-support)

So i have added "Standard architectures" in my build settings to support arm64 and i have setted Build Active Architecture Only to NO. I have made a build with an iphone 6 (with iphone 5 it's all ok) and i have received many error, some of them it's easy to solve, but this error not:

file not found: /Users/*****/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/*****-brhcaqkzbwghmreypofgoustfozt/Build/Intermediates/****.build/Debug-iphoneos/****.build/Objects-normal/arm64/JSONKit.o
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

I have cleared my derived data but it seems that there is some problem with jsonkit library, the library that SThttprequest use do decode json. It's like it isn't compatible with arm64 it is possible?? How i can do to solve the problem? Changing sthttprequest class is a very long work for me... And i think that i can't update my app without 64 bit support...

Comment: You should not use `JSONKIT` I doubt it supports 64 bit. Use NSJsonSerialization instead. See this for more clarification https://github.com/johnezang/JSONKit/issues/135

Comment: [STHTTPRequest](https://github.com/nst/STHTTPRequest/blob/master/STHTTPRequest.m) does not use JSONKit but NSJsonSerialization instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two solutions : NSJsonSerialization or this fork : https://github.com/heroims/JSONKit that can be compiled for 64