# iOS App showing invalid binary, missing 64 bit support

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect, itunes, xcode6.1

When i uploaded iOS app to app store in January last week it shows some warning but still uploaded into iTunes(submission with warnings) and after that I forgot to add demo login account in iTunesConnect. So apple rejected my app.

I have added new demo login for apple and by mistake I uploaded new app also(i don't need to upload a new binary ). Since then, it is showing invalid binary. I have uploaded more than ten times but same thing happening "Invalid Binary".

I tried to validate before submission but validation was "SUCCESS"

I have attached a screenshot of iTunes Invalid binary list here.

[image: Screenshot]

I also tried to create new iOS provisioning profile and tried again to submit to app store. Once I submit I  get message from iTunes that "Invalid Binary" and Organiser not showing status as "Submitted".

Am using Xcode 6.1.1 version.

Mail from apple

[image]

Comment: I have the same problem. I have settings and 64 bits support configured correct. Have you solved your problem?

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple things you must check.

1. Make sure you are making a build with correct distribution & development certificate.

   - To begin with, refresh your certificates in Xcode->Preference->Account
   - Now see the certificates & cross verify its validity on https://developer.apple.com/account/ios/certificate/certificateList.action
2. Your app is 64 bit compatible
3. Use unique build & version number for each upload.

Hope this helps.

Comment: please check the mail i got it form apple

Comment: @Naveenkumarp Very well, now that you know the reason behind it, it should be an easy fix.

Comment: but i couldnt find any issue with 64 bit..please help me

Comment: As its mentioned in the Apple's mail, make sure your app is 64 bit compatible. Also, you need to ensure that all the third party framework is also 64 bit compatible.

Comment: Hope this link helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790554/ios-app-submission-missing-64-bit-support