# iOS App Valid Architecture issue

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I am using xcode version 6.0.1 and uploaded the build on app store test-flight. When I checked its binary details it was showing this

[image]

After this I uploaded this build to App Store and since it was an update of an existing app it was successfully released but as it shows is was not having arm64 architecture and I got mail from apple --> `apps submitted to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK`.

So after adding arm64 by following this answer on stackoverflow [link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790554/ios-app-submission-missing-64-bit-support) my app binary details looks like this
[image]

When I compared it to earlier one this time in supported Architecture armv7s is not showing but arm64 is added. I just wanted to confirm is this right and will this binary be supporting both 32bit and 64bit so that I can go ahead and publish this on App Store.

Adding My Xcode 6.01 build settings tab screenshot after adding arm64.
[image]

Thanks

Comment: You can add armv7s too, just double click the list and click + from bottom and add armv7s, though if you don't add it won't harm anything..

Comment: Change Architecture to Standard Architecture . And Valid architecture to armv7,armv7s,arm64

Comment: Post a snapshot of your architecture settings under Build Settings tab

Comment: Your app was build for 32 bit only.

Comment: Hi adnan added xcode screeshot as you asked. I have already added all three architectures armv7,armv7s,arm64. But still only showing two in supported architectures.

Comment: Have you submitted app with these architecture?

Comment: the image you shared is all set . If they were the architecture settings when you submitted the app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your architecture is similar to below architecture.Then all is well 
[image: Architecture Settings]

Build informations on itunes connect should be as below
[image: Build informations]

Comment: Adnan I have same thing but I have only two schemes Debug and Release not Ad-Hoc and Distribution shown in your screenshot.

Comment: Ok Thanks. Adnan can you check your itunes binary details and tell me did you see same thing as I have posted image on my binary details.(Just need to confirm did u see armv7s in it or not).

Comment: itunesconnect is not accessible .Cannot  confirm

Comment: Thanks adnan for the confirmation and giving your valuable time.