# ERROR ITMS-90086 submitting app

Tags: ios, xcode, ipa

I need to submit my app and I retrieve this error:
[image: error]
and the configuration is on 64 bits:

[image: config]
I don't know how to do...

thanks in advance

Comment: What's under Projectsettings -> Buildsettings -> Valid Architectures?

Comment: armv7 armv7s in target, arm64 armv7 armv7s in project.. if I add arm64 the dropbox sdk retrieve an error...

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/26801060/264822 - you also need to set arm64 in Valid Architectures.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Make sure that for **BOTH**:

- **Project** --> Build Settings --> Architectures

[image: Project --> Build Settings --> Architectures]

**AND**:

- **Targets** --> Build Settings --> Architectures

[image: Targets --> Build Settings --> Architectures]

You have the following **4 things**:

1. `Architectures` set to `Standard architectures (armv7, arm64) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)`
2. `Base SDK` set to some iOS8 SDK, for example `Latest iOS (iOS 8.3)` or `iOS 8.3`
3. `Build Active Architecture Only` --> `Release` set to `No`
4. `Valid Architectures` set to `arm64 armv7 armv7s`

You will then no longer get the `ERROR ITMS-90086`

Comment: And "Apps that only contain the arm64 slice must also have 'arm64' in the list of UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities in Info.plist"... (message I got when trying to submit)

Comment: Step 3 : Build Active Architecture Only to No helped me to get rid of this error

Answer (score 14):

Make sure your "Build Active Architecture Only" setting is set to "No"

Comment: Thanks, Ramy, i've also encountered this issue. You helped a lot :)

Comment: For future readers, the full answer is found here and in above comments.   Setting "Build Active Architecture Only" to "No" is needed, but so is setting armv7 and arm64 in the Projectsettings -> Buildsettings -> Valid Architechtures area.  My project had "Standard Architectures" set, but then arm64 was missing from Buildsettings.  All 3 of these config areas need to be set for the build to be accepted to iTunes.

Answer (score 1):

I case you bought an old app somewhere and are having this error message, also check that the deployment target is set to 8.0 or higher in both the project and the target.