# ERROR ITMS-90086: Missing 64-bit support. Submission fails with error on submit app on iTunes

Tags: ios, xcode, build

I tried to upload my app via Application Loader. But I got an error from the iTunes store.

ERROR ITMS-90086: "Missing 64-bit support - Beginning on February 1, 2015 new iOS apps submitted to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK. Beginning June 1, 2015 app updates will also need to follow the same requirements. To enable 64-bit in your project, we recommend using the default Xcode build setting of “Standard architectures” to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit code."

I already added the arm64 in Xcode like the following picture.

[image]

[image]

What can I do?

Comment: Unplug your physical device from Mac. In XCode on device list choose iOS Device and create Archive again.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/27071693/2073991

Comment: In my case, steps in this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31070414/433543) worked...

Comment: In my case, this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31070414/433543) worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems u are using old device for testing, like iPhone5.
U need change your build target from your iPhone5 or other old iOS device to "**Generic iOS Device**".

Just be Top Right of your XCode

Comment: This should be comment i think.

Comment: Yes! But if you don't have devices then use iOS Simulator option.

Answer (score 9):

In the `Valid Architectures` field of build settings, you should add `arm64` to support 64-bit devices.

Comment: Ok! but I was try to arm64 but that time build fail. I am using xcode 6.1 ios 8.1, But I don't no what is exactly problem?

Comment: Yes you can check on latest Xcode, but, if you don't add the `arm64` to the valid architectures, you can not submit your app to the app store. Just add the `arm64` to `Valid Architectures`, correct the errors you may encounter, and submit the app. Good Luck!

Comment: Im still getting the "Warning"

Comment: Can you provide more details? What warning are you getting?

Comment: My app update gave the same ITMS-90086 warning, although I did update the Architectures to $(ARCHS_STANDARD) and also included arm64 in the Valid Architectures. But when I openend the project.pbxproj in a text editor I noticed my changes in Xcode weren't reflected in this file. I noticed an entry VALID_ARCHS = armv7;

So I updated all entries of ARCHS and VALID_ARCHS to ARCHS = "$(ARCHS_STANDARD)"; and VALID_ARCHS = "arm64 armv7 armv7s";
After restarting Xcode I did get some 64 bit integer warnings and knew 64-bit was now enabled.

Comment: @ShriramKadam did you find out solution? I am facing same issue.

Comment: yes, If you are working on latest IOS or Xcode version  then :--

1)first upgrade your code & select device for Retina Device or 64 bits to work code.
2) If you are using third party library or SDK then remove & install new SDK in application.
3) Check your Valid Architecture in PROJECT & TARGETS options.

Then code Clean, Build & Run. Application will be running successfully.



Hope ! its useful for you...