# Error itms 90086 while submitting app to itunes connect?

Tags: ios

[image][image]I tried changing architectures to standard architectures and set build active architectures to "No", added armv7,arm64,armv7s to valid architectures for both project and target.but still get the error 90086.
 any help is appreciated.

Comment: here no image found , please update your question

Comment: unable to upload the image,it says you require 10 reputation score i have only 9

Comment: Just wait ,i give the upvote, now upload your image

Comment: similar question with   http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29665755/error-itms-90086-missing-64-bit-support-subission-fails-with-error-on-submit

Comment: yes but i followed all the step still get the error

Comment: I also tried upgrading the thirdparty frameworks i used but in vain.

Answer (score 0):

They should be set to as following : 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Here is an answer that resolve that. You should set target and project to standard architecture. [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29567690/error-itms-90086-submitting-app)

Comment: Vote to close as a duplicate rather than posting links to other questions.