# Error 90098: Missing 64bit Support Xcode 7.3

Tags: ios, runtime-error, appstore-approval, cpu-architecture

I am making an app live and I am getting below errors [image]

I googled this error and found these links

[ERROR ITMS-90086 submitting app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29567690/error-itms-90086-submitting-app)

[ERROR ITMS-90086: Missing 64-bit support. Submission fails with error on submit app on iTunes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29665755/error-itms-90086-missing-64-bit-support-submission-fails-with-error-on-submit)

I implemented the solution suggested here as under 
[image]

But error is still same and not getting resolved. Kindly advice if any other solution is available.

Thanks in advance

Comment: What Frameworks/Libs are you using? May be error comes from frameworks/libs? Are they support 64bit arch?

Comment: I am using google framework and Facebook framework

Comment: Also do you try to close/open Xcode, and make clean build?
I dont think that google and fb frameworks results to this error

Comment: I already tried to open and close Xcode. Also I tried this in older and new version of Xcode i.e Xcode 7.2 and 7.3. But same error

Comment: Do you try to run app on iPhone 6? Do you getting linker errors?

Comment: Yes Tried. No errors. Running fine. Even running in iPhone 6S and 6+

Comment: I don't see any issues here, seems that everything is correct. I will suggest to remove Derived Data folder to make sure everything is up to date.

Comment: Didn't understand "Derived Data folder". Please explain

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113111/discussion-between-david-v-and-sanchit-paurush).

Comment: for remove derive data check my answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933321/deleting-contents-from-xcode-derived-data-folder/18933382#18933382

Comment: I already done this @NitinGohel . But no effect

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790554/ios-app-submission-missing-64-bit-support/26796934#26796934