# Missing 64bit Support, Invalid Bundle. Errors when submitting app

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode

I'm trying to submit a new version of my client's app to itunesconnect using Xcode 7 for the first time. When I try uploading it to itunesconnect, I get these 2 errors.

[image]

Anyone else experience this?

Comment: Place linked image inline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**For error 90086:-**

as said by

> [Dave Chambers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1390035/dave-chambers) in [ERROR ITMS-90086 submitting app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29567690/error-itms-90086-submitting-app) this link you need to check all the things.
>
> - **Project** --> Build Settings --> Architectures
>
> [image]
>
> **AND**:
>
> - **Targets** --> Build Settings --> Architectures
>
> [image]
>
> You have the following **4 things**:
>
> 1. `Architectures` set to `Standard architectures (armv7, arm64) - $(ARCHS_STANDARD)`
> 2. `Base SDK` set to some iOS8 SDK, for example `Latest iOS (iOS 8.3)` or `iOS 8.3`
> 3. `Build Active Architecture Only` --> `Release` set to `No`
> 4. `Valid Architectures` set to `arm64 armv7 armv7s`
>
> You will then no longer get the `ERROR ITMS-90086`

and regarding your seond error

**ERROR ITMS-90475**

you need to copy '**Bundle ID**' which is in **iTunes Connect ->manage apps** ->  `**viewed my app**` and

then go to **xcode** and paste into **plist** '**Bundle identifier'** field.

and **restart your xcode** .

and then **delete derived data**.

Here is link for

> **[deleting contents from Xcode Derived data folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933321/deleting-contents-from-xcode-derived-data-folder)**

after this task completed **clean** the project.