# ERROR ITMS-90086: "Missing 64bit support" in xcode 7.2

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, xcode7

I am facing the issue that my app is not going to submit on app store.

I have followed many steps as per suggestions like
[ERROR ITMS-90086 submitting app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29567690/error-itms-90086-submitting-app), but still could not get a solution till now.

How can I sort out this error?

Here is a screenshot of it:

[image]

Comment: What CPU architectures is your app being built for?

Comment: Try to set 'Build Active Architecture Only' build setting to YES or NO on your target

Comment: Deployment target is 7.0

Comment: @heximal

I tried it also. same issue.

Comment: do you use some dependency managers like CocoaPods?

Comment: @heximal
Not using cocopods. Just using third party libraries.

Comment: Make sure your "Build Active Architecture Only" setting is set to "No"

Comment: It's one of two things: You aren't setting the library path correctly or you don't have a version of ZBar SDK that supports `arm64`.  Show the complete linker command line and error output.