# How to update the version of compiled framework

Tags: swift, swift3, frameworks, version

I am using XCode 8.3 and I am trying to Run my project which is connected with [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42510626/xcode-8-2-1-error-no-such-module-youtubeplayer) and now I have a XCode Error: Module compiled with Swift 3.0.2 cannot be imported in Swift 3.1
So my question is how to update the version of the framework?
I downloaded this framework from the link that I've posted above.

Comment: Did you read link question answered?if so which part you won't understand

Comment: I want to compile the framework for Swift 3.1 and I don't know how?

Answer (score 1):

I think that you need to update CocoaPods to a newer version supports XCode 8 (CocoaPods 1.1.0 or newer):

```
sudo gem install cocoapods
```

Then do a pod update to fix your dependencies that are not linking:

```
pod update
```

Delete the DerivedData folder for your project and rebuild, the link error should be gone.

Comment: I don't have CocoaPods I've downloaded the framework from the internet.