# Missing 64-bit Support and Lipo Error!! can't open input file in Xcode 6.3

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, xcode6.3

I downloaded Xcode 6.3 and while Submitting App to the App Store,I'm getting following error's.

In My Build Setting Architecture, If I'm using **Build Active Architectures Only to YES**

[image]

Then I m getting this Error -

> lipo Error!! can't open input file.
>
> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/usr/bin/lipo: can't open input file: /Users/XYZ/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyAPP-hjbmqpnmsoruqxbwlayqkjsojccv/Build/Intermediates/MyAPP.build/Debug-iphoneos/MyAPP.build/Objects-normal/armv7s/MyAPP.

I**f I'm setting Valid Architecture to armv7**

I am getting following error while submitting app to AppStore-

[image]

Comment: Have you tried validating your project settings? Select the project in the Project Navigator and in the menu bar choose: `Editor -> Validate Settings...`

Comment: @Fogh yes i did. but same issue exists

Comment: You should assign "Standard Architectures". Any way, does the answers here help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790554/ios-app-submission-missing-64-bit-support

Comment: @itinance yes i assigned and checked all answers in your given link. but none works.

Answer (score 2):

You are likely using a library that does not support 64 bit. If this is what's causing the problem, you can fix it by updating the library.

The check for this, look at your compiler errors, to see if any point to a third-party library that you're using. They would look something like this:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_THIRD_PARTY_CLASS_NAME", referenced from:
     objc-class-ref in YOUR_CALLING_CLASS.o
```

Don't change the setting for `Build Active Architecture Only`. This should be set to NO for the App Store build, unless you are certain that you only want to build for a device with the exact same architecture as listed in your project settings.