# Error when I tried to submit app to Apple Store

Tags: ios, xamarin-studio

I dont know how can i submit my app to Apple Store again, I'm trying about 2 days, but i get this error below... Can Anybody help me?

[image: Error Xamarin]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/26790554/4151918

Comment: Thanks, but i cannot update my solution :/  is there another thing that can i do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a requirement from Apple that your app must support 64-bit. So you have to [update your project](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26790554/4151918), or they will not accept it. No way around that, if you want it to be on the App Store.