# How to solve "ERROR ITMS-90086: Missing 64-bit support" in iOS App submission from Xcode 6.3.1?

Tags: ios, objective-c, app-store, xcode6.3

I have seen that same question and its not working for me.

When I tried to upload my app to app store, I am getting below error:

> ERROR ITMS-90086: Missing 64-bit support

and I have attached screenshot of full error and my Build Settings screenshot also.

Build settings:

[image]

Error Message

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [iOS app submission : missing 64-bit support](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790554/ios-app-submission-missing-64-bit-support)

Comment: that solution is not working

Comment: Do you import any external frameworks? They would also need 64-bit support.

Comment: i have uploaded same app 1 month before e64 bit support

Answer (score 2):

I was seeing the same issue. My app even passed validation (using the "Validate..." button) but would not upload without yielding the "ITMS-90086" error. Other apps with virtually the exact same code would upload with no problems. Here is how I fixed the problem:

1. Deleted the old archive which generated the error
2. Did a Product->Clean
3. Built and ran the app on a 64-bit device (iPad Air)
4. Created a new archive

I suspect only steps 2 and 4 are necessary. Deleting the old archive and creating a new archive without doing the clean in between most definitely was not enough to get rid of the error, as I attempted that twice unsuccessfully.

Comment: Update: This issue just reappeared for me. I did not build the app on a 64-bit device this time (Step 3 above), but I did have to quit and restart Xcode before I could successfully create a new archive without the problem.