# problemsn with xcode and 64 bit app compatability

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, 32bit-64bit

Hi despite following all the steps indicated in this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790554/ios-app-submission-missing-64-bit-support)

I am still not able to get passed the 64 bit validation on iTunes wondering if anyone can assist please

I have developed the app based on cordova platform yet I use Xcode as the developer interface not sure if this may be a contributing factor ???

Answer (score 0):

Have you connected your devices when archiving the app? If connected, please unplug them, and archive again.

BTW, the common reason is you set "build active architecture only"(in the Building Settings Section) release mode to "yes". So just check that, and change it to "no".

Hope this help you.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply ZuYuan

its set to no, still same problem, i upgraded cordova to the latest version and created a new project and copied the www files etc over to the new project however the app now freezes on the splash screen, no ideas why or how to solve it, the orig app works fine when i test it on my iphone but fails the 64 bit integrity when i upload it. so i am open to either solving the 64 bit problem on the original app  or figure out why the migrated version stalls at the splash screen, yet loads and works perfectly when i run it on safari on the mac fired up from xcode,