# iOS: app doesn't pass the upload for the architecture

Tags: ios, architecture, 64-bit

When I upload my app I have this error

[image]

I set the project and target in this way and the archive has success!

[image][image]

Now you can tell me that I have to add in "valid architectures" the "arm64"
I did it! But my app have some errors during the debug and archive because inside my project there is another workspace called "MapView" that manage maps of OpenStreetMaps.
This workspace settings are:

[image]

Everything I change I have error during debug and archive... my project work well only with the configuration in the pictures, but when I upload ipa in the stor I have the ERROR ITMS for missing 64-bit.

I don't know what can I do!!!

Comment: Do you have added any external framework or library?

Comment: yes I did, is an external framework for OpenStreetMap

Comment: Check that external project setting, and check architecture.

Comment: For architecture I have STANDARD_32_BIT 
for valid architecture I have armv7 e armv7s

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your project architecture and library or framework project architecture would be 64-bit supported.
Please check out below answer

[iOS app submission : missing 64-bit support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790554/ios-app-submission-missing-64-bit-support)