# error uploading ipa on Application Loader

Tags: ios, gradle, javafx, ipa

I have this error when I try to load my ipa on Application Loader:

> ERROR ITMS-90086: "Missing 64-bit support. iOS apps submitted to the App Store must include 64-bit support and be built with the iOS 8 SDK or later. We recommend using the default "Standard Architectures" build setting for "Architectures" in Xcode, to build a single binary with both 32-bit and 64-bit support."

I add this values on my info plist file

```
<key>Architectures</key>
    <string>Standard architectures (including 64-bit)(arm7,arm64)-$</string>
```

And also:

```
<key>Build Active Architecture Only</key>
    <false/>
```

but the problem still exist. 
I use *JavaFx* platform and *javafxmobileplugin*.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you checked this ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26790554/ios-app-submission-missing-64-bit-support

Comment: What is your iOS SDK version ? 

`and be built with the iOS 8 SDK or later`

Comment: I define this :<key>MinimumOSVersion</key>
        <string>7.0</string>

Comment: please disconnect your device and try again

Comment: I did all, but the problem it's not solved :(

Answer (score 0):

You can set minimum iOS version to 8.0 or later.